How do i make the zoomage view listen to single tap?
I have a zoomage view and a bottom navigation view. When i tap on the image view i want the bottom navigation view to dissapear. At the same time, i want the zoomage to still maintain its double tap to zoom and pinch view.
I set up an onclicklistener in the main activity for the image view (To set the visibility of the bottom navigation view). But in doing so the zoomage lost its functionalities.
Here is my xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
        android:id="@+id/image_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:src="@drawable/page1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Here is my java code in main activity:
ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.bottom_navigation);

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(bottomNavigationView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE){
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }else{
            bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    }
});

